# How do i access Node Instances which were built by the NodeFactory on the Server Side in Eclipse Milo?

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

Concerning the implementation on the server side: Which is the best way to access (and modify) specific node instances which were built by the NodeFactory ? 
As an example, in the NameSpaceExample there is a custom object type MyObjectType with components "foo" and "bar".

```
// Define a new ObjectType called "MyObjectType".
    UaObjectTypeNode objectTypeNode = UaObjectTypeNode.builder(server.getNodeMap())
        .setNodeId(new NodeId(namespaceIndex, "ObjectTypes/MyObjectType"))
        .setBrowseName(new QualifiedName(namespaceIndex, "MyObjectType"))
        .setDisplayName(LocalizedText.english("MyObjectType"))
        .setIsAbstract(false)
        .build();

    // "Foo" and "Bar" are members. These nodes are what are called "instance declarations" by the spec.
    UaVariableNode foo = UaVariableNode.builder(server.getNodeMap())
        .setNodeId(new NodeId(namespaceIndex, "ObjectTypes/MyObjectType.Foo"))
        .setAccessLevel(ubyte(AccessLevel.getMask(AccessLevel.READ_WRITE)))
        .setBrowseName(new QualifiedName(namespaceIndex, "Foo"))
        .setDisplayName(LocalizedText.english("Foo"))
        .setDataType(Identifiers.Int16)
        .setTypeDefinition(Identifiers.BaseDataVariableType)
        .build();

    foo.setValue(new DataValue(new Variant(0)));
    objectTypeNode.addComponent(foo);

    UaVariableNode bar = UaVariableNode.builder(server.getNodeMap())
        .setNodeId(new NodeId(namespaceIndex, "ObjectTypes/MyObjectType.Bar"))
        .setAccessLevel(ubyte(AccessLevel.getMask(AccessLevel.READ_WRITE)))
        .setBrowseName(new QualifiedName(namespaceIndex, "Bar"))
        .setDisplayName(LocalizedText.english("Bar"))
        .setDataType(Identifiers.String)
        .setTypeDefinition(Identifiers.BaseDataVariableType)
        .build();

    bar.setValue(new DataValue(new Variant("bar")));
    bar.addReference(new Reference(bar.getNodeId(), Identifiers.HasModellingRule, Identifiers.ModellingRule_MandatoryPlaceholder.expanded(), NodeClass.ObjectType, true));
    objectTypeNode.addComponent(bar);


    // Tell the ObjectTypeManager about our new type.
    // This let's us use NodeFactory to instantiate instances of the type.
    server.getObjectTypeManager().registerObjectType(
        objectTypeNode.getNodeId(),
        UaObjectNode.class,
        UaObjectNode::new
    );

    // Add our ObjectTypeNode as a subtype of BaseObjectType.
    server.getUaNamespace().addReference(
        Identifiers.BaseObjectType,
        Identifiers.HasSubtype,
        true,
        objectTypeNode.getNodeId().expanded(),
        NodeClass.ObjectType
    );

    // Add the inverse SubtypeOf relationship.
    objectTypeNode.addReference(new Reference(
        objectTypeNode.getNodeId(),
        Identifiers.HasSubtype,
        Identifiers.BaseObjectType.expanded(),
        NodeClass.ObjectType,
        false
    ));

    // Add it into the address space.
    server.getNodeMap().addNode(objectTypeNode);

    // Use NodeFactory to create instance of MyObjectType called "MyObject".
    // NodeFactory takes care of recursively instantiating MyObject member nodes
    // as well as adding all nodes to the address space.
    UaObjectNode myObject = nodeFactory.createObject(
        new NodeId(namespaceIndex, "HelloWorld/MyObject"),
        new QualifiedName(namespaceIndex, "MyObject"),
        LocalizedText.english("MyObject"),
        objectTypeNode.getNodeId()
    );



    // Add forward and inverse references from the root folder.
    rootFolder.addOrganizes(myObject);

    myObject.addReference(new Reference(
        myObject.getNodeId(),
        Identifiers.Organizes,
        rootFolder.getNodeId().expanded(),
        rootFolder.getNodeClass(),
        false
    ));
```

With the node factory an instance MyObject of MyObjectType is created which has (due to the type definiton) the components "foo" and "bar". Which is the best way to access them ?
On the client Side it would be something like

`VariableNode node = client.getAddressSpace().createVariableNode(new NodeId(namespaceIndex, "HelloWorld/MyObject"));`

I know it is possible to get the references of MyObject and follow them but there must be a better way.

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking about how to best access them from a client or from within the server?

Comment: @Kevin Ultimately i think i have the same issue as [link] https://github.com/eclipse/milo/issues/239 . During the creation of the adress space on the server (within the server), instances of custom types must be modifiied, i.e. set the attribute delegate. In my understanding you are still working on the node factory to implement some kind of interceptors to allow modifieng the instances during creation by the node factory. Until this is finished i need to get the instances after creation by the node factory and modify them.

Comment: Maybe another problem but related: I have a custom type. It is structured like this: TypeA - Component1- Sub-Component11 (of Component1). Sub-Component11 has modeling rule "optional placeholder". Now when i use the node factory, the instance of TypeA would have no component11 (due to "optional placeholder". I want to add a Sub-Component to the instance A. Thus i nedd to add a component11 and add references from Component1 to this new component11.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get them by surfing references or inferring the NodeId for now.

The new NodeFactory work is done and waiting in a PR for to the 0.3 branch, so hopefully it won't be too long until you can use the NodeFactory implementation.

Comment: Great to hear that you are making progress on 0.3! Could you provide me with a small code sample for inferring a NodeId on server side ? Or point me to an example/ class in the milo project ? Anayway i want to thank you for your time answering me and in general the work you put in eclipse milo.

Comment: The current `NodeFactory` uses the base `NodeId` provided to it and then adds each additional BrowseName separated by `.`. See https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/b4904569cb7bf508d358fa2df665703511fb7246/opc-ua-sdk/sdk-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/sdk/server/nodes/NodeFactory.java#L336-L338 and its usages